# Loading results onscroll down of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

I need to implement face book kind of implemetation like onscroll down of page load more results.
  Styles for Outer Div and inner div

```
  .Outer{
      height: 1430px;
      margin-top: -12px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 99%;
    }
    .inner {
      height: 1435px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      position: relative;
      width: 103%;
    }
```

So for this I have Two divs Inner and Outer and attached inline onscroll function for inner div. I am able to scroll records inside Inner div without scroll bar being visible having 10 records first time the page loads. So when i scroll down to 7th record i need to make server call bring 10 more results append to the Inner div.

What is best way to find scroll position at the 7th record and trigger a server action?

Since website is responsive does Onscroll works well on all devices? Or Any other better approach for the requirement?.

Comment: You should attach an `onscroll` event (see http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php) and you will probably have to use the tricky scrollTop property http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php (notice the warning).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I use the following for now (but i only support Chrome):

```
var handleScroll = function(event) {

        var container = event.target;
        if ((container.scrollTop + container.offsetHeight) 
             + 1 >= container.scrollHeight) { 
             ...
        }
}
```

You basically don't care about the 7th record, just that your user is scrolling to the bottom.

Some additional things you could do:

- add a little animated img (like a rotating circle) for when pulling from the server. I did this by adding an extra div either to the top or bottom of your records based on the scroll direction. Remove it when the server call is done/error.
- a thing to watch out for is too many onscroll calls, if this occurs you may get too many server calls. You could throttle/de-bounce using a timer:

  ```
  document.getElementById('myid').onscroll = function(oEvent) {
      if (this.timer) {
          clearTimeout(this.timer);
      }

      this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
          this.handleScroll(oEvent);
      }.bind(this), 250);
  }.bind(this);
  ```